# The variable is changing when different times called - Python/SageMath

Tags: python, list, math, sage

I'm trying to make a program that gets the "[Kaprekar's constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/6174_(number)#:%7E:text=6174%20is%20known%20as%20Kaprekar%27s,(leading%20zeros%20are%20allowed).)" for base 5 numbers (numbers made from 0 to 4). Part of the process consists saving the numbers I'm getting in a list and repeat the Kaprekar's process, the result is compared with the saved numbers, if it's not in the list, add it and repeat...

The function I made for this:

```py
def constantK(num):
    before=[]
    before.append(num)
    after=kaprekar(num)
    i=0
    while(after not in before):
        if i<5:
            print(before,'--',after)
            i += 1
        before.append(after)
        after=kaprekar(after)
    return [after, len(before)]
```

The `i` and `print` are just for checking what's happening the first 5 times. This is what I get when calling `constantK(base(39,5))`:

```
[[4, 2, 1]] -- [2, 4, 2]
[[4, 2, 1], [4, 2, 2]] -- [1, 4, 3]
[[4, 2, 1], [4, 2, 2], [4, 3, 1]] -- [2, 4, 2]
[[4, 2, 1], [4, 2, 2], [4, 3, 1], [4, 2, 2]] -- [1, 4, 3]
[[4, 2, 1], [4, 2, 2], [4, 3, 1], [4, 2, 2], [4, 3, 1]] -- [2, 4, 2]
```

The `base(a,b)` function just returns a list of the digits for `a` written in base `b`.

As you can see, the value compared is not the same that the one is appended in `before`. I've checking for a while and have no idea why is this happening. I'd be glad with some help

Comment: i made one here:  https://github.com/dlefcoe/daily-questions/blob/master/KaprekarsContant.py   ... it works for 4 digit numbers,

Comment: What does `kaprekar` do? It may be altering the list `after` accidentally.

Comment: For example: `L = []; B = [1,2,3]; L.append(B)`. At this point, `L = [[1,2,3]]`. If you now do `B.reverse()`, then `B` is changed but so is `L`: `L = [[3,2,1]]`.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri I think the problem is exactly what you're saying. `kaprekar(a)` uses `a.reverse()` repeatedly. I just didn't notice about the `.reverse()` implications. I'm gonna have to check it out. I'm open to suggestions about how to replace or rightly use `.reverse()` :)

Comment: `reversed(B)` will produce an iterator with the terms reversed but will not change `B`; maybe that will do what you want.